# In Ruby is there a way to define the context for load?

Tags: ruby

I would like to load a file in a block and evaluate the statements in the context of an instance of a object.  For example something like this:

I have a file called foo_file that contains just this one line (statement)

```
some_method
```

I would like this "statement" to be called in the context of an instance of Foo, as shown below.

```
class Foo
  def some_method
    puts "hello"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

foo.instance_eval  do
    load "foo_file"     # load and execute statement some_method from a foo_file.  
end
```

This fails with:

```
 foo_file:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `some_method' for main:Object (NameError)
```

while this works fine:

```
foo.instance_eval do
  some_method
end
```

So it seems that while I call load in the block passed to instance_eval, the statements are loaded into the top context, not the instance foo.

I can get around this with the code shown below. I create a top level method that wraps a call to the instance method.  I still need to provide the context,  which I accomplish with a singleton.

```
require 'singleton'

class Context
  include Singleton
  attr_accessor :ctx 
end

def some_method
  ctx = Context.instance.ctx
  ctx.some_method
end

Context.instance.ctx = foo
load "bar_file"
```

I think this will work, but it seems like there should be a better way (like just loading into the correct context to begin with).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, getting what you want is quite easy, and doesn't even involve a call to `load`:

```
foo.instance_eval(File.read(file))
```

For example, if `file` just had the text `length`, then

```
"Hello".instance_eval(File.read(file))
```

would return `5`.

More generally, if you want to specify an *arbitrary* context, that's basically the exact situation you'd want to use the optional [`Binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Binding.html) argument to [`Kernel#eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) in:

```
bnd = 'Hello'.instance_exec { x = 3; binding }
eval('length + x',bnd) #=> 8
```

Comment: Please don't use "Edit" or "Update" headers in your text. We can see what was edited and when if we need to. Instead, incorporate the changes into your text as if you'd originally added it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/153968

Comment: @theTinMan: Fair enough. Better?